# I want to know a proper English word to describe a particular kind of television show

Tags: word-request

What is a suitable word for a TV program which is designed for unmarried male and female to come to know each other?

Comment: A dating reality show.

Comment: You need to ask what you originally asked as three seperate questions, since they are all unrelated to each other. P.S. the answer to your previous question 3 would be _greeters_, at least in the U.S.

Comment: I think what the PO wants to know is how unmarried male and female come to know each other to get married later on

Comment: @Leo: I dare say that in _most_ cases, a TV show is not part of the process you describe, so extrapolating from a TV-show to the whole process seems a bit far-fetched?

Comment: @oerkelens - I can't say I agree with you entirely. Because In India on some national and regional level there have been some tv shows where they actually got a few couples married. The shows might not have been much successful, but that's another story. But attempts have been made.

Comment: I have no idea what **you** mean by *designed* or *come to know.*

Comment: @oerkelens You are to be congratulated on your happy ignorance of *The Bachelor*, *The Bachelorette*, *Bachelor Pad*, and *Bachelor in Paradise*.

Comment: @StoneyB: are you saying that indeed these shows now cater for such a vast majority of marriages that indeed a word for such a show _is_ the standard for courtship, like Leo suggested? I only reacted to the (I hope!) deeply absurd notion that this question was about _courtship_ as was suggested in a comment (implying that TV-shows are just a normal part of that).

Comment: @oerkelens Ah, I beg your pardon, I misunderstood: you were responding to Leo's imputation of function to the term *designed*.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the phrase you are looking for is ["Dating game show"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dating_game_show).

> **Dating game shows** are television game shows that incorporate a dating
>   system in the form of a game with clear rules.

Examples might be series like *The Bachelorette*, *Blind Date* etc.

Comment: Or, if you're Chinese, [If You Are the One (game show)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_You_Are_the_One_(game_show))